# scheme - remove odd atoms from a list

Tags: scheme

I feel like I'm close but I can't seem to get this right. Any ideas?

ex)

(removeOdd ‘(8 3 (3 7) 5)) => (8, ())

(removeOdd ‘(5 5 2)) => (2)

```
 (define (removeOdd y)
   (if (null? y) '()
   (if (= (remainder (car y) 2) 0)
       (cons (car y) (removeOdd (cdr y)))
       (cons removeOdd (cdr y)))
   ))
```

This probably won't work for the case with a list being inside another list but I am more concerned about being able to return the list I make with 'cons'

edit - if i switch cons to list it doesn't exactly return the list either.

Comment: `(cons removeOdd (cdr y))` looks very wrong ;p

Comment: There shouldn't be a `,` inside `(8, ())`.

Comment: When you are skipping you shouldn't use `cons` at all. Just recurse with `(removeOdd (cdr y))` That way you are jumping over the even element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (remove-odd y)
  (cond
    ((null? y) '())
    ((pair? (car y)) 
     (cons (remove-odd (car y)) (remove-odd (cdr y))))
    ((= (remainder (car y) 2) 0) 
     (cons (car y) (remove-odd (cdr y))))
    (else (remove-odd (cdr y)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (removeOdd y)
   (if (null? y) 
     '()
      (if (atom? (car y))
         (if (= (remainder (car y) 2) 0)
           (cons (car y) (removeOdd (cdr y)))
           (removeOdd (cdr y))
          )
       (cons (removeOdd (car y)) (removeOdd (cdr y)))
 ))
```

I don't remember actually how to check whether something is atom, but this is what you need.

Comment: I know you can define it and check if it not a 'pair?'